# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when using Hibernate to get data from a database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, javafx

I am testing JavaFX in combination with Hibernate. I want to take user input over a textfield to get a name from the actor table in the sakila database. But every time I try to execute the query, the following errors occur:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.ActorEntity.getActorName(ActorEntity.java:71)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.HelloController.search(HelloController.java:24)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized JPA persistence.xml XSD version : `3.0`
    at org.hibernate.boot.xsd.ConfigXsdSupport.jpaXsd(ConfigXsdSupport.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.validate(PersistenceXmlParser.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
    ... 61 more
```

this is my persistence.xml:

`

```
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
  <class>com.example.demo.ActorEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.AddressEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.CategoryEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.CityEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.CountryEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.CustomerEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.FilmEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.FilmActorEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.FilmCategoryEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.FilmTextEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.InventoryEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.LanguageEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.PaymentEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.RentalEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.StaffEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.StoreEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.ActorInfoEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.CustomerListEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.FilmListEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.NicerButSlowerFilmListEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.SalesByFilmCategoryEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.SalesByStoreEntity</class>
  <class>com.example.demo.StaffListEntity</class>
  <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Sakila"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="ß§%Y-Sn_ß-DF/n-/%D5-m274-§_9s%"/>
  </properties>
```

`

my hibernate.cfg.xml : `

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url"/>
    <property name="connection.driver_class"/>
    <!-- <property name="connection.username"/> -->
    <!-- <property name="connection.password"/> -->

    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`the method that returns the query result:`

```
public String getActorName(String id) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        String query = "SELECT first_name, last_name from actor where actor_id =" + id;
        Query actorQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query);
        List<String[]> actorName = actorQuery.getResultList();
        String result = actorName.get(0)[0] + " " + actorName.get(0)[1];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you see the bottom most exception message, the root cause: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized JPA persistence.xml XSD version : `3.0`"

Comment: I did, but what does it mean?

Comment: Your `persistence.xml` does not look like the [sample in the hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/quickstart/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa-config), it is missing the `version="2.0"` attribute (among other things).

Comment: If you do require version 3.0 of jpa persistence, then you need a hibernate version that supports it (6.0+).